# how to export inside a function in ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, callback, export

I want to (sort of have to) export within a function, I'm using nodejs and prefer to use ES6.
I want to connect to a mongodb and then export the database, and use it somewhere else. so I have to export the database inside the callback function. here is my code:

```
mongodb.connect(connectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client)=>{
    export default client.db();
    app.listen(port);
 });
```

but when I try it, I get this Error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

so how can I export my database properly?

Comment: are you using mongoose?

Comment: @Ifaruki no, I'm not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems we can't do dynamic export in ES6.
The best way to export result of an async function like the one we use for connecting to a database is to use "promises".

```
export default new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongodb.connect(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {
        if (err)
            reject(err);
        resolve(client.db());
        app.listen(port);
    });
});
```

then we can import it in the consumer file, and use it as below:

```
import dbPromise from './db.js'
function someFunction() {
   dbPromise.then((result) => {
      //if we want to insert some data to database
      result.collection('collectionName').insertOne(data);
   });
}
```